# IndexError: tuple index out of range, error when trying to integrate the fucntion

Tags: python, tuples, quad

I am trying to calculate a value of function `f_integ`, which is a result of integration of function `f` from 0 to `x_v`.

```
   f = lambda x : x + 1

    def f_integ(x_array):
        int_result = np.zeros_like(x_array)
        indexes = np.shape(x_array)[0]
        for ind in range(indexes):
            x_v = x_array[ind]
            int_result[ind] = integ.quad(f, 0.0, x_v)[0]
        return int_result

    C = f_integ(1)
    print "C", C
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 117, in <module>
    C = f_integ(1)
  File "scr1.py", line 110, in f_integ
    indexes = np.shape(x_array)[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I know that `quad()` returns a tuple, but I can not figure out how to put a number as an argument in the result of integration. I'm new to Python, please help.

Comment: Post the full error message, including the stack trace, and a [mcve] as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function like this:

```
C = f_integ(np.array([1]))
print "C", C
```

Currently you are passing a number to `f_integ()`, not an array. When it encounters `np.shape(x_array)[0]`, the shape of a number is just `()`, so it cannot return anything at index 0 for an empty tuple.

Comment: Good catch. But it has a shape just fine, but that shape is an empty tuple, which will throw an IndexError with anything you try to index into it.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you accept the answer since it worked for you?